# cannot retrieve many to many all objects in django

Tags: python, django, django-admin

when i try to retrieve all cart items from order model then click to open cartitem model edit page but i got first cart item only so what is wrong my code

**Admin Model**

```
class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('user', 'total_price', 'ordered',
                    'get_address', 'get_cart')

    def get_cart(self, obj):
        for p in obj.items.all():
            app_label = p._meta.app_label
            model_label = p._meta.model_name
            url = reverse(
                f'admin:{app_label}_{model_label}_change', args=(p.id,)
            )
            return mark_safe(f'<a href="{url}">{p.item}</a>')

    get_cart.allow_tags = True
    get_cart.short_description = "Cart"
```

**Order Model**

```
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(CartItem,)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    total_price = models.FloatField(default=0)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    payment_id = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=100)
    ordered_date = models.DateTimeField()

    address = models.ForeignKey(
        Address, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-ordered_date']

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user.username) + ' '+str(self.total_price)

    def user_link(self):
        return '<a href="%s">%s</a>' % (reverse("admin:auth_user_change", args=(self.user.id,)), escape(self.user))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop in `get_cart` returns after processing the first object.

You could construct a safestring with the required links before returning, e.g.:

```
def get_cart(self, obj):
    x = []

    for p in obj.items.all():
        app_label = p._meta.app_label
        model_label = p._meta.model_name
        url = reverse(
            f'admin:{app_label}_{model_label}_change', args=(p.id,)
        )

        x.append(f'<a href="{url}">{p.item}</a>')   

    x = ' | '.join(x)
    x = mark_safe(x)
        
    return x
```